# Simulating GC moving memory

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, clr

I have some work with native .dll's. And so i want to test some obscure cases of GC acting on resources currently used in native code.

For now i'm using the fact that this line:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("");
```

Makes GC instantly move memory used all classes. But obviously, this is an awful way to do it. It's not only undocumented behavior (so i can't expect it to be truly reliable), but also only works once per program run.

So the question is, is there proper way to simulating GC moving memory? I would be fine with anything, even directly calling internal CLR methods, as long as it's supposed to work by definition.

Comment: interesting question (presumably you're trying to test for broken references=>pointers that weren't correctly fixed/pinned/etc in the managed code), but I doubt you can reliably *force* GC to do that - it probably won't have anything to compact most of the time, even if you ran `GC.Collect`, waited for finalizers, etc; it won't move things "just because", and once you've compacted *once*, you're usually unlikely to suddenly get huge holes in the space before the bits you've used with native code. Another approach, of course, is: not to use managed memory here - use unmanaged allocations etc.

Comment: As far as I know these moves only happens during compaction. I can't see why writing to Debug would trigger that and even if it did, there would be no reason to move all objects. Do you have any info on this undocumented behavior?

Comment: @MarcGravell the whole point is to be able to make safe managed wrapers that take managed types and send them to unmanaged code (or back), copying everything to unmanaged memory would just kill performance.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen no, i have no idea why it works, that's exactly why i don't like using it. Though i was still able to get some interesting results with it.

Comment: @SunSerega assuming you're talking about `struct` here: you can use them in unmanaged memory; the entire point of which being to *avoid* ever copying them. Historically you had to use `unsafe` for this, but these days: `Memory<T>` and `Span<T>`, and `ref T` mean you don't end up with `unsafe` / `T*` polluting your code

Comment: @MarcGravell i'm mostly talking about sending arrays of struct's (but not only) back and forth without copying. I was testing which methods of passing them are safe.

And well, yeah, what i found out for now - anything with `unsafe` is (unironically) unsafe for all non-GCHandle-pinned types heap memory (like arrays, contents of other classes). But only when pass but reference (and not `ref`-parameter).
And passing them as a `ref`-parameter, just as an array, etc. - is always safe.

Comment: But the main question asked here is still open: What is non-cheatty way of doing what `Debug.WriteLine` does for me?

Comment: "is (unironically) unsafe for all non-GCHandle-pinned types heap memory" - managed arrays etc without your own fixed/pin should safe for the duration of a single P/Invoke call; but no longer (i.e. the unmanaged code shouldn't store the pointer); but again: I think you'd do very well to look at unmanaged memory instead here, via Memory-T; happy to help if that is of interest

Comment: @MarcGravell no, as i said - copying to unmanaged memory and back is not the main option, as it would be unnecessary slowdown. Though this is already supported by my code.

Comment: @SunSerega you're misunderstanding me; forget about copying it there and back; imagine a world where your structs lived **only** in the unmanaged memory, but without `unsafe`. No copying, ever. No pinning, ever. Just `Span<T>`, `ref T` (and pointers for the P/Invoke). That world exists today.

Comment: @MarcGravell ah right. Well no, that's also not an option, because regular managed arrays are still more popular, so i at least need to support them.